# Slicing array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Sample array,

```
# sub-arrays are all of the same length
arr = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7]]
```

Now,

```
arr.some_slicing_technique(0..2)
```

should give me,

```
[[1,2,3], [5,6,7], [2,4,6], [1,3,5]]
```

Does `some_slicing_technique` exist? What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7]].map {|e| e.take(3)}

=> [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Or if you want to use ranges:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7]].map {|e| e[0..2]}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could transpose the original array, remove the last block and transpose it again:

```
arr.transpose[0..2].transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more generic:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7]]
slice_lambda = lambda { |r| lambda{ |x| x[r]} }
arr.map(&slice_lambda[0..2])
# => [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
arr.map(&slice_lambda[1..2])
# => [[2, 3], [6, 7], [4, 6], [3, 5]]
```